# Getting Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null in spring tomcat application

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am getting the following exception while getting datasource through jndi:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
     Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
     org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null
```

Tomcat's server.xml :

```
     <Resource name="jdbc/testdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="test" password="test1234"
          url="*********"
          driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
          initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
          maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
```

Tomcat's Context.xml :

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/testdb" global="jdbc/testdb"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Spring's servlet xml :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/testdb"  resource-ref="true" />
```

and final Web.xml :

```
   <resource-ref>
       <description>Resource reference to database</description>
       <res-ref-name>jdbc/testdb</res-ref-name>
       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
       <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Could somebody please help me?

Error Stack trace :

```
  Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Did you actually write the url `**********` there? Or are you trying to hide the URL from us? Because it appears that the URL is the problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : I am writing actual url there but I am hiding here .

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : added stacktrace.

Comment: And the actual URL is? Appears to be empty to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `driverClassName` instead of `driverClass`:

```
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
```

Comment: I tried with driverClassName but getting same error.

Answer (score -1):

> I am using Eclipse STS 3.9.3, tomcat 8.5 and Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

I spent my entire morning about this problem.
So, I did a lot of things to solve:

1. Remove jdbc dependence from my pom.

   ```
       <!-- dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency-->
   ```
2. Declaration resource TOMCAT_HOME/CONF/server.xml whit factory:

   ```
   <GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
      <Resource name="jdbc/postgres_jndi"
                 auth="Container"
                 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                 driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                 url="jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5432/db"
                 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                 removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
                 removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
                 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
                 removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
                 logAbandoned="true"
                 username="xxx"
                 password="xxxxxx"
                 maxTotal="20"
                 maxIdle="10"
                 maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
    ...
   </GlobalNamingResources>
   ```

   I realized that I was using Eclipse STS. The tomcat resource on server.xml only works after I put the resource declaration in server.xml inside of "Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost-config" folder in my Server project. Did not work on TOMCAT_HOME/conf folder in server.xml file.
3. Change my application.yml to:

   ```
   spring:
     datasource:
       platform: postgres
       jndi-name: java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres_jndi
       type: javax.sql.DataSource
       driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
     jpa:
       hibernate:
         ddl-auto: validate
       database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
       database: POSTGRESQL
       show-sql: true
       #Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
       properties:
         hibernate:
           temp:
             use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
   ```

I think that you miss **java:comp/env/** yours will be like this:
`<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/testdb" resource-ref="true" />`

A application.properties will be like:

```
    spring.datasource.platform= postgres
    spring.datasource.jndi-name= java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres_jndi
    spring.datasource.type= javax.sql.DataSource
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= validate
    spring.jpa.hibernatedatabase-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    spring.jpa.database= POSTGRESQL
    spring.jpa.show-sql= true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

4. Define a context.xml file in src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml with definition:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context path="/myapp">
       <ResourceLink global="jdbc/postgres_jndi" name="jdbc/postgres_jni" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
   </Context>
   ```
5. Put the file postgresql-42.2.2.jar in the TOMCAT_HOME/lib

Comment: so, what caused the problem?

Comment: I see two things:
1. He does not declared the context in application, but in tomcat context.
2. I don't know if he declared the Resource in the server.xml tomcat between GlobalNamingResources tags.
I put my solution for he compare with he has and figureout whats is happing.

Comment: A third thing: try <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/testdb"  resource-ref="true" />